# F# Function Parameter is Shown as Null by the IDE but it has a Value

Tags: f#

I am currently reading Real World Functional Programming and I have a question with respect to one of the code snippets, namely 3.10

It is an example that deals with pattern matching. Taking a look at the following screenshot, I can’t understand why tuple is null at that point in the execution (at that breakpoint):

[image]

As I understood it, tuple was a parameter that was being passed into the withSecond function.

If anyone can explain to me why that identifier should have a null value at that point, that would be great.
Cheers

**Edit**

Adding code:

```
let printCity(cityInfo) =
    printfn "Population of %s is %d."
            (fst cityInfo) (snd cityInfo)


let withSecond newItem2 tuple =
    let (originalItem1, originalItem2) = tuple // Decompose a tuple into two values
    (originalItem1, newItem2) // Use 'f' as a first and 'nsnd' as the second element

  // Increment population and print the new information
let prague0 = ("Prague", 1188000)
let prague1 = withSecond ((snd prague0) + 13195) prague0
printCity prague1

System.Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
```

Comment: short answer: it should **not** - and I guess it's just another instance of the debugging behavior we sometimes see with F# - try selecting another stack-frame and reinspect (or step-on and see that you will get the desired result)

Comment: BTW: please copy&paste the real code here - if there is indeed something we have to try out it's kindof *painful* to have to retype everything from a screenshot ;)

Comment: @CarstenKönig Thanks Carsten. I totally understand your point. The  screenshot was more for the demonstration of what the ide was showing me. But I also agree that I should have posted the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter `tuple` isn't null. This is a bug in the debugger that you run into sometimes with f#.

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tUpxfc) is a dotnetfiddle showing it isn't null.

The variable `prague0` is passed to the function. So `tuple` within the function is the same as `prague0`.

I've seen this happen lots of times while debugging f#, this also become rather weird when you inspect `this` at certain points. The debugger is really `c#` oriented. Watch statements should also be written in `c#` for example.

When you inspect things a bit further you'll notice the function signature after compilation is: `withSecond<int,string,int>(int newItem2, string tuple_0, int tuple_1)` This explains why the debugger can't find `tuple`. If you add a watch to `tuple_0` you'll see it containts `"Prague"`.

[image: function signature]
[image: watches]